# enquire about/ on

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Which is grammatically correct?

I am writing to enquire ***about*** any job opportunity

or

I am writing to enquire ***on*** any job opportunity

Comment: "Enquire about" is correct. "Enquire on" is not. I will wait for someone to post an answer that provides grammatical justification.